# AngularJS option length IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, element

I have option list of some types like car, bus in format like this: `<option value="BUS" label="Bus">Bus</option>` and when I want to count the length of the list I use `angular.element(element[0].options).length` in Chrome it returns the correct length, but on Internet Explorer it returns 1

Comment: What does `element[0].options.length` return?

Comment: It returns the correct amount 27, but when I use angular.element(element[0].options).length it returns 1. Firefox also returns the correct amount when using angular.element(element[0].options).length it seems that it's only reproducing for IE and Edge

Comment: If you found my answer helpful please mark it as accepted. Likewise if you figured out a different fix then post that as well so others may benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Use `element[0].options.length` directly, instead of wrapping it in `angular.element()`. If your list is data driven (which I recommend) then you can also just check the length of your array that contains the data.

```js
var list = document.getElementById('list');

console.log('list.options.length = ' + list.options.length);
```

```html
<select id="list">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

Regarding the data driven list, ideally you should have an array of vehicles/transports/anything (might be complex objects with properties or just unique strings). Once you expose that array to the view (via scope or `this` from `controllerAs` syntax) then you can generate the list of options using [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). For example:

Controller JS:

```
$scope.items = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'aLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'bLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
}];
```

Template HTML:

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```